# How to make div insert avatar on ionic7, like this image

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I want to make this on ionic 7 with ionic avatar using scss. But im still did'nt get it. How to made this?

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNc0H.png)

this is my scss code

```
ion-avatar {
  --border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  top: 12px;
  ion-avatar::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #00AB9A;
  }
}
```

and this is my html code

```
<ion-avatar>
<div>
<img alt="avatar" src="/assets/avatar-equipment.png"/>
</div>
</ion-avatar>
```

I've try to make this using scss ::before ::after, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

like some workaround:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukiyyc

```
 <ion-avatar>
  <img
       alt="Silhouette of a person's head"
       src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/img/demos/avatar.svg"/>
  <div class="corner"></div>
 </ion-avatar> 

 .corner {
   position: relative;
   top: -53px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
   border-width: 0 0px 50px 50px;
   border-color: transparent transparent #00ab9a transparent;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
```

But it will be much better to create separate custom angular component and to use default css styles with pseudo-element ::after.